# How to stop blending between layers?

Tags: html, css, blending

I'm playing around with blend modes to achieve a combined image that has a shirt and a pocket. It all looked good when I was at the point of just having *shirtVer* and *shirtHor* layers. I could combine them and change the colors of the checkers pattern without problems. Then I wanted to add the pocket, and did so. But because they are blended using multiply the end result ends up being a mixture of all four layers. And that is not what I want to achieve.

How can I achieve that there is a break in the blending between (shirtVer+shirtHor) and (pocketVer+pocketHor)?

HTML

```
<span class="img-position shirtVer">
</span>
<span class="img-position shirtHor">
</span>
<span class="img-position pocketVer">
</span>
<span class="img-position pocketHor">
</span>
```

CSS

```
.img-position {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 768px;
    height: 768px;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.shirtHor {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('img/shirtHor.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/shirtHor.png');
}

.shirtVer {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url('img/shirtVer.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/shirtVer.png');
}

.pocketHor {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: url('img/pocketHor.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/pocketHor.png');
}

.pocketVer {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url('img/pocketVer.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/pocketVer.png');
}
```

The current result looks like this, where you can see that the shirt and pocket are blended together.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, thanks to a dear friend. I added a middle layer, that has the base shape, and do not perform mix on that layer. Solution:

HTML

```
<span class="img-position shirtVer mix">
</span>
<span class="img-position shirtHor mix">
</span>
<span class="img-position pocketBase">
</span>
<span class="img-position pocketVer mix">
</span>
<span class="img-position pocketHor mix">
</span>
```

CSS

```
.img-position {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 768px;
    height: 768px;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.mix {
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.shirtHor {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('img/shirtHor.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/shirtHor.png');
}

.shirtVer {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url('img/shirtVer.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/shirtVer.png');
}

.pocketBase {
    background-image: url('img/pocketFull.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/pocketFull.png');
}

.pocketHor {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: url('img/pocketHor.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/pocketHor.png');
}

.pocketVer {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url('img/pocketVer.png');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('img/pocketVer.png');
}
```

And final result, as expected:

[image]